# Using Mapnik comp-op to mask out raster layer using a vector layer

Tags: python, gis, gdal, mapnik, cartography

I'm trying to make a map with Mapnik using separate datasets for the land and sea.

Land is a raster dataset from Landsat imagery.  Ocean is a raster dataset created with gdaldem from NOAA bathymetry.

The Landsat dataset includes ocean imagery, but it's ugly.  I want to knock it out so we see thru to the NOAA bathymetry layer below, creating a look similar to the Blue Marble maps.

I thought I could use a third layer containing a PolygonSymbolizer based on a world boundaries vector dataset as a mask, by setting the symbolizer's comp-op to dst_in and dropping it on the very top of a layer stack like this:

- VECTOR MASK (COMP-OP DST_IN)
- LAND RASTER
- SEA RASTER

I've tried every alpha comp mode and can't get it to work.  What am I missing?  Or maybe there's a much easier way?

Here's a gist of my code...
https://gist.github.com/john-sanders/800b973858bc13e4417c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a step back, it seems I was using the wrong tool for the job.  Or at least not the easiest tool for the job.

gdalwarp has a -cutline parameter that accepts a shapefile to knock out unwanted raster data.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/gdalwarp-cutline-along-with-shapefile

Also, it appears this question would have been better asked at gis.stackexchange.com